# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation Problem with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have windows 8.1 in my PC and want's to install Ubuntu with it. When i run the setup and boot to that point where it ask for different options, i choose Install inside windows 8.1. It said reboot is required to run the installation. And when i restart the PC the setup wont run and windows boot automatically. I tried many times and watched some videos also and followed the same procedure but nothing happen. Please help me solve the problem. I don't format my derives because they all got useful data. So the only option is install along side windows...
Thank for advance

Comment: Are you trying to install it inside Windows, see Wubi install. If you are trying to install it alongside Windows - Use one of the Dualboot Windows answers, or try reading the How To Dualboot Windows in Full Circle Magazine! fullcirclemagazine.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi is no longer supported by Canonical.  See the forums recommendations
[Ubuntuforums Staff WUBI Recommendations](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766)

You can still install to another device (USB stick or disk), run Ubuntu in a virtual machine, or shrink a partition to make room for more Ubuntu partitions.  Adding partitions is only tricky if the Vendor has already used the 4 allowed Primary partitions.  In that case, you need to copy the data off one, delete it, shrink the adjacent one (if necessary for more room), and create an extended partition (counts as a primary). Inside the extended partition, you can add many logical partitions.

---

You use the same ISO for virtual machines as the regular downloads.  See the VirtualBox information in the community documentation [Title Index for docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TitleIndex).  It may not be for Windows, but I know VirtualBox runs under Windows.  Installing to a USB is no different than installing to any other device, select it in the installer, partition it, and install.  There are some optimizations you can apply to improve performance -- search the forums and questions for tips, but basically, they all boil down to moving things like /tmp into a ramdisk.

Comment: Okay Thanks... I was thinking about Virtual Machine, Where can i find its ISO file, i searched at Ubuntu website but didn't find, and is it available in current version of Ubuntu 14.04... ?

Comment: And please elaborate me how can i install Ubuntu on disk or USB stick.